# Value of expression involving coefficients of an equation and its complex roots.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

It is given that $\cos\alpha + i \sin\alpha$ is the solution of the equation

$$x^n + P_1x^{n-1}+ \cdots +P_n=0$$ where all the coefficients are real.

Then what is the value of $$P_1\sin\alpha+P_2\sin2\alpha+ \cdots + P_n \sin n\alpha$$

By substituting $n=1$ and $P_n$ an arbitrary real value, it is easily seen that $\alpha=n\pi$ and hence the value is $0$.

But how can this be proved for any values of $n$ and the other co-efficients in the equation?

Comment: Is it supposed to be $P_1x^2$ or $P_1x^{n-1}$?

Comment: Oops! I've changed it. Thanks for suggesting the edit.@kingW3

Comment: $P(e^{i\alpha}) = 0 \implies \Im\left(e^{-in\alpha}P(e^{i\alpha})\right) = 0$. Now express RHS using $\sin\alpha, \sin(2\alpha),\ldots$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once we have:

$$x^n + P_1x^{n-1}+ \cdots +P_n=0 \quad (1)$$

divide everything by $x^n$ and get:

$$1 + P_1x+ P_2x^{-2}\cdots +P_nx^{-n}=0 \quad (2)$$

If $\cos \alpha + i\sin \alpha$ is root of $(1)$ then $(\cos \alpha + i\sin \alpha)^{-1}=\cos \alpha - i\sin \alpha$ is root of $(2)$.

Use that $(\cos \alpha - i\sin \alpha)^m=\cos (m\alpha) - i\sin (m\alpha)$, so:

$$1 + P_1x+ P_2x^{-2}\cdots +P_nx^{-n}=\\
=1+P_1[\cos (\alpha) - i\sin (\alpha)]+P_2(\cos (2\alpha) - i\sin (2\alpha))+...+P_n(\cos (n\alpha) - i\sin (n\alpha))=0$$
so,

$$P_n\cos (n\alpha)+P_{n-1}\cos ((n-1)\alpha)+...+P_{1}\cos (\alpha)+1=0$$
$$-i[P_n\sin (n\alpha)+P_{n-1}\sin ((n-1)\alpha)+...+P_{1}\sin (\alpha)]=0$$

and

$$P_n\sin (n\alpha)+P_{n-1}\sin ((n-1)\alpha)+...+P_{1}\sin (\alpha)=0$$

Comment: Will the same be true if these equations involved complex coefficients?

Comment: @AnanthKamath: Nope! I can write $$-i[P_n\sin (n\alpha)+P_{n-1}\sin ((n-1)\alpha)+...+P_{1}\sin (\alpha)]=0$$ only if $P_i\in \Bbb R$.

Comment: Okay.  Thanks for sharing your knowledge @Arnaldo.